# Using #include to load OpenCL code

Tags: c++, c, opencl, c-preprocessor

I've seen this done long ago with hlsl/glsl shader code -- using an `#include` on the source code file that pastes the code into a `char*` so that no file IO happens at runtime.

If I were to represent it as pseudo-code, it would look a little like this:

```
#define CLSourceToString(filename) " #include "filename" "
const char* kernel = CLSourceToString("kernel.cl");
```

Now of course that `#define` isn't going to work because it'll just try to use those quotation marks to start strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the bullet physics engines use of OpenCL for [how](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/trunk/Demos/VectorAdd_OpenCL/MiniCL_VectorAdd.cpp?r=2106) to do this to a [kernel](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/trunk/Demos/VectorAdd_OpenCL/VectorAddKernels.cl?r=2106).

In C++ / C source

```
#define MSTRINGIFY(A) #A
char* stringifiedSourceCL = 
#include "VectorAddKernels.cl"
```

In the OpenCL source

```
MSTRINGIFY(
   __kernel void VectorAdd(__global float8* c)
   {
    // snipped out OpenCL code...
    return;
   }
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if your .cl file contains commas that are not contained between parentheses, like "int x, y;", it ends your string after "int x".

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246301/c-c-can-you-include-a-file-into-a-string-literal), it's not possible, but you can use `xxd -i` to archieve the same effect.